# Float object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I fix the error in my code. Whenever I try to run it, the 'float' object has no attribute '**getitem**' keeps on appearing. I am trying to put all the computed values in a table-like format but the error keeps on appearing. 
Here is the code. It's a bit longer than I imagine. The error is at the end in for i in range...

```
sumlat = 0.0
sumdep = 0.0
sumdist = 0.0
lat1 = []
dep1 = []
d1 = []
northings = []
eastings = []
adjdep = []
adjlat = []

import math
n = input('\nEnter Number of Corners:')
northings += [input('Northings of Point 1:')]
eastings += [input('Eastings of Point 1:')]

def compLatDep (b, d): #function compLatDep
    return (b, d)
def degAzi (deg, mi, sec): 
    return (deg, mi, sec)

#I.
for i in range (0,n):
    if n > i+1:
        print '\nLine %d-%d.' % (i+1, i+2)
else:
    print '\nLine %d-%d.' % (i+1, 1)
    b = raw_input('Azimuth (from the South in D-M-S):') #follow the format     in entering the given azimuth
    myString = b
    deg = myString.split("-")[0] #myString.split("-") method results to an input string split and returned the list of string split
    deg = float(deg)
    mi = myString.split("-")[1]
    mi = float(mi)
    sec = myString.split("-")[2]
    sec = float(sec)
    decimal = deg + (mi/60) + (sec/3600) #conversion of dms into decimal degrees
    d = input('Distance (in meters):')
    d1 += [d]
    sumdist += d
    lat, dep = compLatDep (b,d)
    dep = -d * math.sin(math.radians(decimal)) #the azimuth should be converted into radians for this import/formula to work, given formula in finding the dep of a corner
    dep1 += [dep]
    sumdep += dep
    lat = -d * math.cos(math.radians(decimal)) #given formula in finding the lat of a corner
    lat1 += [lat]
    sumlat += lat
```

## II. Corrections and adjustments to be applied in each corner

```
for i in range(len(dep1)):
    corr = -sumdep *  d1[i] / sumdist #formula in finding the correction to be applied in each departure
    corrdep = corr + dep1[i] # formula for corrected departure of each corner
    adjdep += [corrdep]
for i in range(len(lat1)):
    corr = -sumlat *d1[i] / sumdist #formula in finding the correction to be applied in each latitude
    corrlat = corr + lat1[i] #formula for corrected latitude of each corner
    adjlat += [corrlat]
for i in range(len(lat1)):
    north = northings [i] + lat1 [i]
    northings += [north]
for i in range(len(dep1)):
    east = eastings [i] + dep1 [i]
    eastings += [east]
```

## III. REC and LEC

```
 LEC = math.hypot(sumlat, sumdep) #imported from math module to find the LEC     of a closed loop traverse
 print '\n\tLEC: %f' % LEC
 print '\tREC: 1:', (sumdist/LEC)
 print '\t   : 1:', (int(sumdist/LEC)) #rounded down to the nearest integer
```

## IV. (this has a problem)

```
 print '%s\t%10s\t%14s\t%14s\t%14s\t%14s\t%14s' % ('Line', 'Azimuth', 'Distance', 'Adj Lat', 'Adj Dep', 'Northings', 'Eastings')

for i in range (1,(n+1)):
     if(i == n):
        print '%d-%d\t%10f\t%14f\t%14f\t%14f\t%14f\t%14f' %(i, 1, decimal[i], d1[i], adjlat[i], adjdep[i], northings[i], eastings[i])
    else:
        print '%d-%d\t%10f\t%14f\t%14f\t%14f\t%14f\t%14f' %(i, i + 1, decimal[i], d1[i], adjlat[i], adjdep[i], northings[i], eastings[i])
```

Comment: You should try to reduce this to a [MCVE] but you're getting that error because one of the parameters in your giant print is not a list but a plain float. Try `3.0[2]` in the REPL to see the exact same error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A couple of things: please provide the full stack trace so that we can see exactly what happened. Also, please work to minimize the code to the smallest amount that still produces the error. This is a lot of code to ask people to sift through. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it looks like it might be `decimal` - there is no `decimal[i]`